# impossible open excel file through getOpenFilename

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to open in another application an excel file through a dialog window an excel.
I found this code in another post. However I don't get to open the file.
I think the issues are in these lines of the code:`If sFilePath = False Then` and `Set wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(sFilePath, False)`
I'm also trying to open a file .xlsx

```
Sub OpenFile()

' Create Excel object
'    On Error Resume Next
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    
    ' Prompt user to select Excel file to read from
    ' Alternatively, you could hard code the filepath like this:
    Dim sFilePath As String
    sFilePath = excelApp.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", Title:="Select excel file")
'    ' Open Excel file invisibly
    If sFilePath = False Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(sFilePath, False)
    End If

   End Sub
```

Comment: What does "I don't get to open the file" mean?

Comment: Have you attempted with hardcoding xlsx rather than using a wildcard?  I believe you would want to hardcode each of the relevant extensions: xlsb, xlsx, xls, & xlsm.

Comment: Declare `sFilePath` As Variant, else it cannot be `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Excel From Another Application

**The Mistakes**

- `Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")` or `Set xlApp = Excel.Application` will reference an existing instance of Excel. If Excel isn't open (there is no instance), an error will occur.
- `.GetOpenFileName` will return the file path (a string) or the boolean `False`. If you use a string variable, the boolean `False` will be converted to the string `"False"` so you can use the string to test if the dialog was canceled.

**First Solution (Early Binding)**

- For example, if you want to open an Excel file from Word, you can create a reference to the Excel library and develop your macro almost as if you were in Excel e.g. all the objects from Excel will be available in the Word's IntelliSense.
- To reference a new instance of the Excel Application object using early binding, you will use:

  ```
  Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
  ```

**Second Solution (Late Binding)**

- If you don't want to create a reference to the Excel library and/or you want to send the file to someone and you don't want to bother him/her with the details on how to create a reference, you will use late binding when you won't have access to the Excel objects' IntelliSense.
- To reference a new instance of the Excel Application object using late binding, you will use:

  ```
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  ```

**A Few Details**

- Whether Excel is already open or not, these codes will create a new instance that you will want to close after you're done.
- To do this correctly, you have to account for possible errors occurring which is done by using an error-handling routine.
- So whatever happens, in the end, the new Excel instance needs to get closed.

**The Codes**

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenFileUsingExcelReference()
' Needs a reference to 'VBE>Tools>References>Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library'
    Const ProcName As String = "OpenFile"
    
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Workbook

    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const FileFilterString As String = "Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*"
    Const TitleString As String = "Select Excel file"
        
    ' Reference a new invisible Excel application object.
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application ' CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True ' when done developing, out-comment this line
    
    ' Prompt user to select Excel file to read from
    Dim sFilePath As String
    sFilePath = xlApp.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:=FileFilterString, Title:=TitleString)
    If sFilePath = "False" Then
        Err.Raise 1004, , "You canceled the dialog."
        'MsgBox "You canceled."
    End If
    
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFilePath, False)
    
    ' Continue, e.g.:
    Debug.Print "The workbook '" & wb.Name & "' has " _
        & wb.Sheets.Count & " sheet(s)."
    
SafeExit:
    
    ' Close the workbook and quit.
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    If Not xlApp Is Nothing Then xlApp.Quit
    
    Exit Sub
    
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub

Sub OpenFileWithoutExcelReference()
' No reference needed (*** indicates the differences)
    Const ProcName As String = "OpenFile"
    
    Dim xlApp As Object '***
    Dim wb As Object '***
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Const FileFilterString As String = "Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*"
    Const TitleString As String = "Select Excel file"
        
    ' Reference a new invisible Excel application object.
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") '***
    xlApp.Visible = True ' when done developing, out-comment this line
    
    ' Prompt user to select Excel file to read from
    Dim sFilePath As String
    sFilePath = xlApp.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:=FileFilterString, Title:=TitleString)
    If sFilePath = "False" Then
        Err.Raise 1004, , "You canceled the dialog."
        'MsgBox "You canceled."
    End If
    
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFilePath, False)
    
    ' Continue
    Debug.Print "The workbook '" & wb.Name & "' has " _
        & wb.Sheets.Count & " sheet(s)."
    
SafeExit:
    
    ' Close the workbook and quit.
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    If Not xlApp Is Nothing Then xlApp.Quit
    
    Exit Sub
    
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code a little bit, you may have the problem on the line where you're trying to evaluate a string to a boolean value as stated by @FunThomas, but I could think of at least another scenario that may be happening/will happen: the file may be opened by another process. I modified your code a little to address that scenario, this should be working or display the proper message if it doesn't.

```
Sub OpenFile()
Dim VarValueFromMsg As Variant
Dim WBToImport As Workbook
Dim TxtFileToImport As String
' Create Excel object
'    On Error Resume Next
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    ' Prompt user to select Excel file to read from
    ' Alternatively, you could hard code the filepath like this:
    VarValueFromMsg = excelApp.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select excel file", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", MultiSelect:=False)
    On Error GoTo Err01OpenFile
    If VarValueFromMsg = False Then Exit Sub
Err01OpenFile:
    TxtFileToImport = CStr(VarValueFromMsg)
    If Return_IsExcelFileLocked(TxtFileToImport) = True Then Exit Sub
    Set WBToImport = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=TxtFileToImport)
End Sub
Function Return_IsExcelFileLocked(TxtFile As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    ' If the file is already opened by another process,
    ' and the specified type of access is not allowed,
    ' the Open operation fails and an error occurs.
    If Dir(TxtFile) = "" Then MsgBox "Error01Return_IsExcelFileLocked: File does not exist.": Return_IsExcelFileLocked = True: Exit Function
    Open TxtFile For Binary Access Read Write Lock Read Write As #1
    Close #1
    ' If an error occurs, the document is currently open.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ' Display the error number and description.
    MsgBox "Error02Return_IsExcelFileLocked: #" & Str(Err.Number) & " - " & Err.Description & ": If file is open please close it."
    Return_IsExcelFileLocked = True
    Err.Clear
    End If
End Function
```